# viewWillTransitionToSize called even if i press power button

Tags: objective-c, ios9

While my app is running and i press power button (To lock the device) this function is calling.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

And returning current state `UIApplicationStateActive` using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState
```

How to prevent calling this function ? or how to ignore if power button is press? because i don't want to perform any action on powerButton press.

**Precondition : Launch Screen should be present.**

Comment: when you lock a device , the application state will be UIApplicationStateInactive. You can check for this flag and perform operations or do nothing!

Comment: many times its returning UIApplicationStateActive

Comment: looks like it first return StateActive and then it returns StateBAckground. Maybe you should look for StateBAckground

Comment: its always returning UIApplicationStateActive, sometimes background, don't know when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function calling on app minimise and power button press due to new feature of multitasking.
You can make your application full screen to solve this problem.

Check on `✓ Requires full screen`

[image]

But this is not the proper solution because you have to adopt multitasking in some case.

Comment: "make your application full screen" does not "solve" the problem. It is simply a thing you can do whose *side-effect* circumvents the behavior noted by the original question. While certain app contexts make sense to require a full screen (3D games, for example), "Don't let your users participate in multitasking." doesn't really get to the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this behaviour. It seems this happen only on iPads and maybe it related to split view function.

Try to ignore the code running inside the method by adding at the beginning of the method:

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
return;
}
```

UPDATE:

I found the cause of this issue.

When you press "power" button, the application window changes their size and sometimes it happens before the application sets the correct applicationState:

[image] 
[image]

That's why this method calls.
Sorry for my english =)

Comment: Yes, iPad and Split view,

Comment: But while pressing power button its returning UIApplicationStateActive

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Very strange, but I have next:

'(lldb) po [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState
UIApplicationStateBackground'

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I investigated this behaviour, please look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thats not the problem, actually when you press power button, viewWillTransitionToSize calls before applicationWillResignActive.

Comment: @Rajneesh071, As I understood, there is no way to prevent calling this method when you tap the power button because of the screen size value changes. Also tap handling is allowed only for Jailbroken devices.

You can check the applicationState in the completion of animator:

[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        
    }];

Comment: @Rajneesh071, if you find any solution, please notify me in this post =)